# jquery change element partially working

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble changing text in an element that is near another element. The function is fairly straightforward, but for some reason I can't get this text change to work.

When I click on #dislike_text, it goes blank (as it should), but the .like_text doesn't change. Note that there is also a postlike function (identical to this one, but reversed, which works fine).

```
function postdislike(elm) {

    var comment_id = $(elm).attr('href');

    $('#stuff').load(// --function-- 

      function (data) {

        $('#dislike_text' + comment_id).html(""); //works fine
        $(elm).closest('.like_text').html('Like'); //doesn't work
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You should add some HTML to show us and 'prettify' this JQ

Comment: $('#stuff).load( is missing a ' is that a mistype?

Comment: @BrunoVieira - No, I just cut out all of the function stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`closest` goes up through the ancestor elements and finds the first that matches the selector.  If there are no ancestor elements with the class `like_text`, no elements will be selected.

I presume you do not mean to blank an ancestor element, since that would have the effect of removing the `#stuff` element.  You therefore need to find your way to the other element in some other way, using jQuery's [traversing functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/Traversing/).  The most likely way to do this is to use `closest` to find a common ancestor, and then `find` to get the element itself.  For instance:

```
$(elm).closest('div.someClass').find('.like_text').html('Like');
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! Have upvoted and will accept as soon as it lets me (4 minutes).